# Java, rsa encryption

Tags: java, encryption, rsa

So I have a byte array and I want to encrypt this array using rsa, but also I want to leave first byte untouched like this:

```
//Before encryption:
byteArray[0] = 1;
byteArray[1] = 0;
byteArray[2] = 1;

//After encryption:
byteArray[0] = 1; //untouched
byteArray[1] = -127; //encrypted
byteArray[2] = 230; //encrypted
```

Which method of doFinal I should use?

@edit
Why this isn't working?

```
        try
        {
            byte[] pack = new byte[4];
            byte[] pack2;
            byte[] pack3;
            pack[0] = 1;
            pack[1] = 2;
            pack[2] = 3;
            pack[3] = 4;

            System.out.println("START!");
            for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                System.out.println(pack[i]);
            }

            KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
            keyPairGenerator.initialize(512);
            KeyPair keyPair = keyPairGenerator.genKeyPair();

            Cipher cip = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
            cip.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keyPair.getPublic());
            pack2 = cip.doFinal(pack, 1, pack.length-1);
            for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                System.out.println(pack2[i]);
            }

            Cipher cip2 = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
            cip2.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, keyPair.getPrivate());
            pack3 = cip2.doFinal(pack2, 1, pack2.length-1);
            for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                System.out.println(pack3[i]);
            }

            System.out.println("END!");

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

and output is:

> ```
> START!
> 1
> 2
> 3
> 4
> 111
> -44
> 120
> 103
> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've updated your code a little. Look for the comments I've inserted.

Essentially, RSA returns a block of data (cipher-text) when you encrypt that is significantly larger than your data (plain-text). This is by design. In your case, since you are using 512-bits for your key length, you can expect a 512-bit (64-byte) output block from enciphering the plain-text. To decipher the cipher-text you **MUST** have the entire block of cipher-text to perform a decrypt.

```
try
{
    byte[] pack = new byte[4];
    byte[] pack2;
    byte[] pack3;
    pack[0] = 1;
    pack[1] = 2;
    pack[2] = 3;
    pack[3] = 4;

    System.out.println("START!");
    System.out.println("pack");
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        System.out.println(pack[i]);
    }
    System.out.println("");

    KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
    keyPairGenerator.initialize(512);
    KeyPair keyPair = keyPairGenerator.genKeyPair();

    Cipher cip = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
    cip.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keyPair.getPublic());
    // I think you said you wanted the last 3 bytes encrypted
    //                        vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
    pack2 = cip.doFinal(pack, 1, pack.length-1);
    System.out.println("pack2");
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        System.out.println(pack2[i]);
    }
    System.out.println("");

    Cipher cip2 = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
    cip2.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, keyPair.getPrivate());
    byte[] pack3Tmp= cip2.doFinal(pack2, 0, pack2.length);
    pack3= new byte[pack.length];
    // Copy over the first byte you had mentioned to be 
    // unecrypted
    pack3[0]= pack[0];
    // Use System.arraycopy
    //               Source is pack3Tmp
    //               |         Starting offset is 0
    //               |         |  Destination is pack3
    //               |         |  |      Staring offset in pack3 is 1
    //               |         |  |      |  Copy all of pack3Tmp
    //               |         |  |      |  |
    //               v         v  v      v  v
    System.arraycopy(pack3Tmp, 0, pack3, 1, pack3Tmp.length);
    System.out.println("pack3");
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        System.out.println(pack3[i]);
    }
    System.out.println("");

    System.out.println("END!");
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: No, because as the user stated the first byte of pack[] is not encrypted. But pack3Tmp is the result of decryption. The encrypt was 3 bytes so your decryption output is 3 bytes.

Comment: Sorry, yeah. Missed that this was decryption and not encryption because so much scrolling.

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with RSA, it's just basic Java programming mistakes. `pack2[0]` through `pack2[pack2.length-1]` contain the result of encrypting `pack[1]` through `pack[pack.length-1]`. Thus, in order to decrypt successfully, you must supply `pack2[0]` through `pack2[pack2.length-1]`. Since you supply the decryptor with `pack2` starting `pack2[1]` your code should throw a decryption error exception, not the exception you are reporting. Therefore I have to also conclude that code you provided and the output you provided don't go together.

If you want to copy the first byte of pack to pack2 you have to do that yourself, perhaps with the assistance of one of Arrays.copy*() methods and/or System.arraycopy().

Answer (score 0):

You should use `byte[] doFinal(byte[] input, int inputOffset, int inputLen)` specifying `1` as the input offset and the length of the array as the input length.

In your case: `doFinal(byteArray, 1, byteArray.length)`